# error in script undefined id

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

This morning this scipt was working perfectly, but now I am getting an error on line 7 that id is undefined:-

```
<?php
     $m = new mysqli("localhost","scott","tiger","movie");
     if($m->connect_errno){
         die("Database connection failed");
     }
     $m->set_charset('utf8');
     $id = $_REQUEST["id"];
     $sql = "
     SELECT name,title, movieid
        from casting 
        join actor on (actorid = actor.id)
        join movie on (movieid = movie.id)
        where actorid=$id";

     $res = $m->query($sql);
     while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
         echo "<p>$row[name] - <a href=movies3.php?id=$row[movieid]>$row[title]</a> </p>";
}
```

Comment: Can you share html code ??

Comment: this code seems ok to me (on line 7) ... but look at the code that posts the request

Comment: this is is all code and it used to  read data from databases

Comment: `$_REQUEST["id"]` that, is coming from somewhere. *where?*

Comment: If you access to your page directly, obviously `$_REQUEST` is empty: you have to click to a link to send request.

Comment: fred li i respect your words but in my practical it"s writen to make request

Comment: sir please run this scipt it does not allow me  to click

Comment: @DennisKhullar Yes, you are right. I suppose that last row loads same page, but now I see that you find actorid, not movieid. BTW, you have to load htttp://yoursite/yourpath?id=yourID to load an id

Comment: oh yes silly me thankyou so much sir how should thumbs up to your answer so can get credits

Comment: You can check the _unexpected_ existing answer. Side note: not an error, but better, standard syntax: `echo "<p>{$row['name']} - <a href=\"movies3.php?id={$row['movieid']}>{$row['title']}</a> </p>"`

Comment: thankyou so much bro

Comment: how to show actor name once and all movies

Answer (score 0):

This script required id in the request

### Method 01 : Get Method

Access script via url having id in the query parameter with value.

ie. http://localhost/youscript.php?**id=7**

### Method 02: Post Method

Request page via form sending post data to your page.

```
<form method="post" action="your-page-url">
 <input name="id" type="text" placeholder="Enter your id" required>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

make sure you have the field with name="id" attribute and it has value.